# How to set by default scroll for WebDataGrid at the bottom of the grid

Tags: .net, infragistics

Currently , we set the scrolltop as follows:

```
   webGrid.ScrollTop = dt.Rows.Count * 30;
```

where dt contains the total data for binding into the webgrid. But when huge data is present in datatable and after setting scrolltop property, the webGrid.Rows.Count is reducing which is causing issue. Kindly help to set scroll bottom for webgrid without reducing the webGrid rows count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned rows count reducing, does this means that you are using Virtual Scrolling, and not all rows are loaded initially?

As for you question there is easy way to implement this on the *client*. You can get the scroll container height - *$("#WebDataGrid1 table[role='grid']")* .. and use scrollTop in order to scroll to the bottom of the container.

```
var height = parseInt($("#WebDataGrid1 table[role='grid']").css("height"));
ig_controls.WebDataGrid1._container.scrollTop = height;
```

Comment: Where to place the above code? Does not work in document.ready and also in function on 'Add New' button click. I guess these lines are executed and then WebGrid is loaded.

Comment: Noticed that 'VirtualScrolling RowCacheFactor' was set to 100. May be because of that row count reduced. Increased it to 1000 and scrollTop property is working fine.

Comment: You can place the code in WebDataGrid Initialize client event, in order to be applied correctly the Grid should be rendered, so :

        function WebDataGrid1_Init(sender, eventArgs) {
            var height = parseInt($("#WebDataGrid1 table[role='grid']").css("height"));
            ig_controls.WebDataGrid1._container.scrollTop = height;
        }
...
As for the Virtualization, I am glad that I've managed to help you.

Comment: Giving the above code for initialize client event does not work. A performance issue is found by increasing the rowcachefactor. Can you please suggest better approach

Comment: VirtualScrolling will allow you to configure the size of the row cache, this means that if you want to scroll down to the latest row, the approach that I suggested you will scroll only to the latest rendered row in the container. If you want to scroll all the way down to the last row from the data source, you shouldn't use virtual scrolling.. the main benefit of this feature is to cache the rendered rows and not to overload the DOM. RowCacheFactor with value 1000 is not recommended.

Comment: "For example, if WebDataGrid has a view port of 10 rows with the RowCacheFactor set to 3, the row cache equals 30 rows. If you scroll to row 101, you would see rows 101 through 110 in the view port. The additional cached rows out of view are rows 91 through 100 and rows 111-120. If the ThresholdFactor is .5 and the view port contains 10 rows, the threshold is at 5 rows from the end of the row cache. So in this example, the threshold would be at rows 95 and 115. If you scroll to one of these rows WebDataGrid makes a request for additional rows."